# How to pass parameters to DI container at runtime with factory in Akka.NET?

Tags: c#, autofac, akka.net

I have a parent class named `SearchEngineSupervisor` which creates instances of `SearchEngineWorker` as child actors.  I need to pass an instance of the class `SearchEngine` to the child `SearchEngineWorker` class when it's created at runtime in addition to a few other dependencies.

Without using DI, this would look something like:

```
var props = Props.Create(() => new SearchEngineWorker(searchEngine, dependencyA, dependencyB));
var childRef = Context.ActorOf(props, "SearchEngineChild");
```

However, I'm using DI (Autofac) and there is no overload of the Props method on the DI extension which accepts parameters.  This is my only option:

```
var props = Context.DI().Props<SearchEngineWorker>();
```

In any other environment, I would leverage Autofac and inject a factory delegate such as `Func<SearchEngine, SearchEngineWorker>` to the `SearchEngineSupervisor` parent class which I would then invoke with the single `searchEngine` parameter to create the child.  Autofac would then inject the given parameter along with other dependencies of the child class.

I tried using the following:

```
var props = Props.Create(() => _workerFactory(searchEngine));
```

But this throws an exception, as the Create method is expecting an expression of type NewExpression, not InvocationExpression:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression'.
```

I've attempted several variations on the above theme in attempt to disguise the invocation, including with a concrete `ISearchEngineWorkerFactory` object, but all of my attempts thus far have been thwarted, resulting in a similar `InvalidCastException.`

In the meantime, I'm injecting the child's dependencies into the parent `SearchEngineSupervisor` class and instantiating the child class directly in the `Props.Create` delegate, as in the example above.

Comment: `Props.Create` works only with lambda expressions made of a single **new** statement. Reason for this is that whole props must be serializable (while C# expressions aren't) and in fact passed lambda is a deconstructed internally as constructor call with list of serializable arguments, which can be passed over the wire and constructed on the other node if needed.

Comment: @Horusiath That makes a lot of sense, thanks!  Then I believe my best bet will be to refactor the extra dependencies out of `SearchEngineWorker` into a new, separate actor which I can interact with from within the worker using messages.  That's a better design anyway!